# Join with conditional IN with Doctrine2

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

Not even sure this is possible, but it **looks** like it should

In my `Video` entity, I've got a ManyToOne associate for the `Product` entity

Here, I am trying to acquire all published products, and acquire the videos that belong to that product with a Join

```
// ProductRepository.php
public function findPublished()
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $q->select(['p', 'v'])->from($this->getEntityName(), 'p')
        ->leftJoin('p.videos', 'v', 'ON', 'p IN v.products')
        ->where('p.published = :published')
        ->setParameter('published', true);

    $results = $q->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

The Exception that comes back is this:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 76: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT p, v FROM Company\CoreBundle\Entity\Product p LEFT JOIN p.videos v ON p IN v.products WHERE p.published = :published
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you would use `WITH` as opposed to `ON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entities are mapped correctly, you don't need to specify the join condition. Try this

```
$q->select(['p', 'v'])->from($this->getEntityName(), 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.videos', 'v')
    ->where('p.published = :published')
    ->setParameter('published', true);
```

Comment: Ok so the only way this would work is to persist the associated videos to the product. Which there are currently none however. Up until this point, it's been `Video` entities that have a `Product` `ManyToOne`, I've no need to change that, but I'm now just trying to create a reverse search, acquiring `Product` entities and their associated `Video`. I'm using the `join` as something of a mount point. Is this going to need a sub select instead?